# In Keras, does a simpleRNN always need to be followed by a dense layer?

Tags: keras

It seems that in principle anyway, a simple RNN should be able to function standalone as it generates outputs and states for each input. All the examples I see have a dense layer following the RNN though, and my models won't build without one.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

In classification problems, Simple RNN acts as a feature extractor while the Dense layer acts as a classifier.